# Incrementing Score in Swift when SpriteNode goes off screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have searched this a lot and couldn't find anything which could help. 
I am creating a game in SpriteKit using Swift 3.

SpriteNodes spawn on the right hand side of the screen and using SKActions make their way to the left hand side of the screen where this repeats.

I need a way that when the SpriteNode passes my player (in the middle of the scene) the score goes up by one.

The Following Block moves my enemy character from Right-To-Left.

```
func createEnemyBird() {
    // Create Enemy Bird 1
    enemyBird1 = EnemyBird(imageNamed: "enemy 1")
    enemyBird1.position.x = self.frame.width + 100
    enemyBird1.position.y = CGFloat.randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: -(self.frame.size.height / 2.8), secondNum: (self.frame.size.height / 2.4))
    enemyBird1.name = "EnemyBird1"
    enemyBird1.initialise()

    print(enemyBird1.position.y)

    // Add Physics Bodys
    enemyBird1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.height/10)
    enemyBird1.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    enemyBird1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    enemyBird1.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    // Add Collision Bitmasks
    enemyBird1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Pipes

    // Animate Enemy Bird
    var enemyBirdAnim = [SKTexture]()
    for i in 1..<5 {
        let enemyName = "enemy \(i)"
        enemyBirdAnim.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: enemyName))
    }
    let animateEnemyBird = SKAction.animate(with: enemyBirdAnim, timePerFrame: 0.08, resize: false, restore: true)
    enemyBird1.run(SKAction.repeatForever(animateEnemyBird))

    // Make enemy Bird Move Left
    let destination = self.frame.width * 2;
    let move = SKAction.moveTo(x: -destination, duration: TimeInterval(6));
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent();


    // Run Enemy Bird Mobe
    enemyBird1.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]), withKey: "Move")



    // Add Children to scene
    self.addChild(enemyBird1)

}
```

I also have a function But i do not know when to call it

```
    // Score increase
func incrementScore() {
    if enemyBird1.position.x == -(self.frame.size.width/2) {
        score += 1
        scoreLabel.text = String(score)
    }
}
```

I tried to add an SKAction Run Block calling it in the sequence but that didn't work very well as about 6 enemy characters passed before it actually started counting (which is weird)...

Comment: Any code as far as what you've tried for scoring method and players position would be of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add your `incrementScore` function inside the `update` method on your `SKScene`:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    if !enemyBird1.isScored {
        if enemyBird1.position.x > -self.frame.size.width / 2 {
            score += 1
            scoreLabel.text = String(score)
            enemyBird1.isScored = true
        }
    }

}
```

The `update` method will fire every frame and check to see if the bird has passed the center of the screen. If it has, it will be marked as having scored so it won't be counted again.

This will require you to add an `isScored` property to your `EnemyBird` class.

Assuming your `EnemyBird` is an `SKSpriteNode`, it will look something like this:

```
class EnemyBird: SKSpriteNode {

    var isScored = false

    // other properties, inits, functions, etc

}
```

Comment: Will give this a go, VERY new to swift, how would i add a isScored property to enemyBird class?

Comment: This works! but for some reason the score starts on 2 and the score changes when the enemyBird1 is in the exact enter of the screen not the far left edge.

Comment: @LukeTerzich As for the center of the screen, it's because you specified  -(self.frame.size.width/2)` in your original question. This would need to be changed based on where your scene's anchor point is located. As for starting on 2, this depends on where and how the bird is added to the scene. I don't have enough information to debug that.

Comment: Turns out i was calling the createEnemyBird() function twice! Your method was spot on for scoring and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You could consider overriding `position` in EnemyBird to call a function whenever the position of the bird changes. For example, inside the EnemyBird class, you could add something like:

```
 override var position: CGPoint {
    didSet {
        if self.position.x == theParentSceneLeftEdge {
        // call a function to update score
        } 
    }
 }
```

EnemyBird would then also need to know the value of `theParentSceneLeftEdge`, which you could assign to equal to the value of your scene's left edge when you init EnemyBird.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the whole thing with just SKActions. Just split the move into two parts: first move to the score line, then move the rest of the way. And in between, update the score. This code replaces the "Make enemy Bird Move Left" and "Run Enemy Bird Mobe" sections in `createEnemyBird()`:

```
// first action moves to the score line
let scoreLineDestination = -self.frame.width / 2
let moveToScoreLine = SKAction.moveTo(x: scoreLineDestination, duration: TimeInterval(3));

// second action calls your incrementScore() method
let increment = SKAction.run(self.incrementScore)

// third action moves the rest of the way
let finalDestination = -self.frame.width * 2;
let moveToFinal = SKAction.moveTo(x: finalDestination, duration: TimeInterval(3));

// finally remove
let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent();

enemyBird1.run(SKAction.sequence([moveToScoreLine, increment, moveToFinal, remove]), withKey: "Move")
```

You can also drop the position check from `incrementScore()` since you know it won't get called until a bird crosses the score line:

```
func incrementScore() {
    score += 1
    scoreLabel.text = String(score)
}
```

That way you don't have to worry about which bird is calling it.

Comment: for some reason the score goes up very quick by the time 1 bird has passed the score is on about 100.

Comment: @LukeTerzich When I put the code into a new project it works as intended: the score increments exactly once per bird. It sounds like maybe you're calling `incrementScore()` from somewhere else, like maybe the `update()` or `position()` functions mentioned in other answers. Make sure it only gets called by `SKAction.run()` and nowhere else.

Comment: That was exactly what had happened,  Both answers to my question worked. A+ Robert!